# Maximizing MainForm incorrectly

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

In Delphi setting the `WindowState` of a form to `wsMaximized` should make it display as a maximized window.

I see in the sourcecode that the effect is performed using the WinAPI call `ShowWindow(HWND, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)`.

The Window is shown maximized indeed.

The only problem is under Windows 10 the form tries to occupy the whole screen instead of the whole workarea. This leaved the bottom if the form hidden from the user by the taskbar. Under Windows 7 this works correctly.

Is there a possible workaround for this problem?

Comment: Are you using VCL styles?

Comment: Yes, I am using VCL styles.

Comment: So there's the problem. A VCL styles bug. Prob rodrigos utils fixes it

Comment: @David: I will try the VCLStyleUtils to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Does not seem to work. As a workaround I hook OnResize and adjust with SetBounds.

Comment: I'd submit a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround you can add this code to the form in question:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  B: TPoint;
begin
  R := BoundsRect;
  if ( R.Top <= 0 ) and ( R.Bottom >= Screen.DesktopHeight ) then begin
    R := Screen.WorkAreaRect;
    B.X := GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSIZEFRAME  ) - 1;
    B.Y := GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSIZEFRAME  ) - 1;
    SetBounds( R.Left - B.X, R.Top - B.Y, R.Right - R.Left + B.X * 2, R.Bottom - R.Top + B.Y * 2 );
  end;
end;
```